# Ionic 4 Routing Upgrade/Migration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When using [Ionic 4 with Angular](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-4-angular-routing). You can use the Angular router instead of Ionic routing with **NavController**. I started developing an Ionic 3 application for a while now. Now I want to migrate my project to use Ionic 4 instead. How to properly migrate to Angular routing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to migrate your Ionic 3 application to Ionic/Angular v4 for anyone in the same situation.

First generate a brand new Ionic/Angular v4 application using the Ionic CLI 4. This way, you don't need to create the new structure manually:

```
ionic start newproject blank --type=angular
```

### Moving Files from Ionic 3 Project to Ionic 4 Project

Move the files from the `src` folder in your Ionic 3 application to the `src/app` folder in your Ionic 4 project.

### Update Imports

Change imports from `ionic-angular` to imports from `@ionic/angular`.

### Update Routing

Ionic/Angular v4 uses the Angular router for routing while Ionic 3 uses Push/Pop stack navigation with **NavController**

First you need to create all the routes that your application has in the `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'list', loadChildren: './pages/list/list.module#ListPageModule' },
  { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './pages/detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule' },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

You can now navigate between different pages by injecting the router and calling:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor( private router: Router) {}

navigateToHome(): void {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
}
```

You can find a list of breaking changes from this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md)

You can use this [TSLint rules for Ionic Angular v4 Migration](https://github.com/ionic-team/v4-migration-tslint) which warns about and automatically fix syntax changes listed in the breaking changes file using tslint, codelyzer, and the Angular compiler.

Comment: Not!! Working for me. Can you please help. Error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:119"

Comment: When migrating from ionic 3 to ionic 4, all my pages are not created in angular format. (Eg. I do not have the .module.ts file) Do I need to convert it in order for the routing to work. I have try something like this { path: 'schedule', loadChildren: './pages/schedule/schedule.ts#SchedulePage' } but it doesn't work. Please advise.

Comment: @kangalert I am also facing this issue. Did you find any solution?